# Concatenar sub items de lista array

Tags: javascript, array, concatenación

Tengo una lista array de la siguiente manera:

```
const opcUserPais = {
Argentina: {
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    value: "0000 000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png",
},
Brazil: {
    pais: "Brazil",
    codigo: "+55",
    regular: /^([0-9]{3})$/,
    value: "00 0000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png"
},
Paraguay: {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png"
},
```

};

Quisiera mostrar todas las banderas en una lista `ul`, pero no puedo acceder al mismo.
La forma menos posible de codigo y escribiendo en el DOM lo hago así sin resultados:

```
let opciones = [];

opcUserPais.forEach((item) => {
    opciones += `
        <li class="opcion"><img src="${item.bandera}"> <span>${item.pais}:</span> (${item.codigo})</li>
    `;
});

userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;
```

Gracias y feliz año nuevo

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es usar una cadena no una lista: let opciones="";

Comment: Pero si quieres meter en una lista todas las opciones entonces debes usar la funcion push,  no +. opciones.push( `<li class="opcion">... `);

Comment: Yo solo quiero uno: por ejemplo la bandera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que los arrays clave/valor no tienen un `foreach`, pero si podemos usar un simple bucle `for`:

```JavaScript
for (let i in opcUserPais){
    opciones += `
        <li class="opcion"><img src="${opcUserPais[i].bandera}"> <span>${opcUserPais[i].pais}:</span> (${opcUserPais[i].codigo})</li>
    `;
}
```

Al usar el operador `in` en el bucle `for` lo que haces es iterar sobre las claves del `array`.

```js
const opcUserPais = {
Argentina: {
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    value: "0000 000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png",
},
Brazil: {
    pais: "Brazil",
    codigo: "+55",
    regular: /^([0-9]{3})$/,
    value: "00 0000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png"
},
Paraguay: {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png"
},

};
let userOpciones=document.createElement("ul");

let opciones = "";

for (let i in opcUserPais){
    opciones += `
        <li class="opcion"><img src="${opcUserPais[i].bandera}"> <span>${opcUserPais[i].pais}:</span> (${opcUserPais[i].codigo})</li>
    `;
}

userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;

document.body.appendChild(userOpciones);
```